# How to loop through a string then find if a part of that string is in an arrayList

Tags: java, regex, string, arraylist

What I am trying to do is to find loop through a string then match them with an arrayList.

Say, I got this code working:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.*;

public class Test_Mark4 {
    public static ArrayList<String> patterntoSearch;
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {
        String text = "Lebron James";
        patterntoSearch = new ArrayList();
        patterntoSearch.add("Lebron James");
        patterntoSearch.add("Michael Jordan");
        patterntoSearch.add("Kobe Bryant");
        System.out.println(patterntoSearch);
        System.out.println(text);
        boolean valueContained = patterntoSearch.contains(text);
        System.out.println(valueContained);
    }
}
```

However, what if I replace `String text = "Lebron James";` with `String text = "Lebron James 2017-218 NBA Hoops Card";`? Clearly there is the string `Lebron James` in that string, but it got mixed with other words as well (which I would not care, and only care about the string `Lebron James`. I have thought about a `for` loop but unsure how to construct it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression for that:

```
patterntoSearch.stream()
    .anyMatch(s -> text.matches(".*" + s + ".*"));
```

This returns `boolean` indicating whether any element in `patterntoSearch` is contained in `text`.

```
patterntoSearch.stream()
    .filter(s -> text.matches(".*" + s + ".*"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will return a list of words in `patterntoSearch`, that are contained in `text`. If you want only one, then:

```
patterntoSearch.stream()
    .filter(s -> text.matches(".*" + s + ".*"))
    .findAny()
    .orElse(null);
```

I have passed `null` as default, but you can provide any `String`.